# Zero amount transfer?

Tags: smart-contract, tokens, transfer

I just want to use EOSIO as a DB of some events by sending transactions when other events fire. Is it possible to send ZERO amount transfers? The events are millions a day, and I don't know how to calculate the initial token supply if the amount of the transfers is greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep track of events by simply calling `actions`. An example of an action is a `transfer`, but you can make arbitrary actions using a smart contract. In this way you can have a very modular way to keep track of the events on chain.

An example way you could do this is as follows (in a smart contract):

```
ACTION zerotransfer(std::string const & data_to_store_on_chain){}
```

If you know the specific data associated with certain events, you can make this type safe:

```
ACTION registername(std::name const & myname){}
ACTION changenumber(double const number){}
```

And so on

Answer (score 1):

If you remove [line 93 from eosio.token.cpp](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.token/src/eosio.token.cpp#L93)

```
        check( quantity.amount > 0, "must transfer positive quantity" );
```

you will be able to send zero amount transfers.

But to be honest, that doesn't sound like a good and smart idea.

If you want to use EOSIO as database without the need to execute logic that depends on the state of the blockchain that's not the right way and it doesn't seem that you need a token for whatever you are trying to build.